# Custom Admin Menu Order for all User Roles

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, menu-order

I've reordered the admin menu items through:

```
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {
if (!$menu_ord) return true;

return array(
    'index.php', // Dashboard
    'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
    'edit.php?post_type=sp_faq', // FAQs
    'gf_edit_forms', // Forms
    'woocommerce', // Woocommerce
    'edit.php?post_type=product', //Products
    'edit.php', // Posts/News
    'edit.php?post_type=event', // Events
    'upload.php', // Media
    'themes.php', // Appearance
    'plugins.php', // Plugins
    'users.php', // Users
    'tools.php', // Tools
    'options-general.php', // Settings
);
}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order'); // Activate custom_menu_order
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

This works great for the Admin user role, however, does not work for other roles. How do I extend this custom menu order to all user roles?

Comment: Anybody? Nobody?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether you are trying to make all of these items available to all user roles (which would mean having to add custom capabilities) - so I'm assuming you only want the ability to customize menu order by user.

My approach for this was to get all roles available to the currently logged-in user, and then run each role through a switch to get the appropriate order.

```
function my_custom_menu_order( $menu_ord) {
$curr_id = get_current_user_id();
$user = new WP_User( $curr_id );
if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role ){
        switch($role){
            case 'administrator':
                if (!$menu_ord) return true;
                return array(
                'options-general.php', // Settings
                'index.php', // Dashboard
                'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
                'edit.php?post_type=faq', // FAQs
                'options-general.php', // Settings
                'gf_edit_forms', // Forms
                'woocommerce', // Woocommerce
                'edit.php?post_type=product', //Products
                'edit.php', // Posts/News
                'edit.php?post_type=event', // Events
                'upload.php', // Media
                'themes.php', // Appearance
                'plugins.php', // Plugins
                'users.php', // Users
                'tools.php', // Tools   
                );
            break;
            case 'editor':
                if (!$menu_ord) return true;
                return array(
                'edit.php?post_type=event', // Events
                'index.php', // Dashboard
                'edit.php?post_type=page', // Pages
                'edit.php?post_type=faq', // FAQs
                'options-general.php', // Settings
                'gf_edit_forms', // Forms
                'woocommerce', // Woocommerce
                'edit.php?post_type=product', //Products
                'edit.php', // Posts/News
                'upload.php', // Media
                'themes.php', // Appearance
                'plugins.php', // Plugins
                'users.php', // Users
                'options-general.php', // Settings
                'tools.php', // Tools   
                );
            break;

            default:
            break;
            }
       }
}

    add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'my_custom_menu_order');
    add_filter('menu_order', 'my_custom_menu_order');
```